# Override set_value function in screen OrderWidget POS odoo-12

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-12, pos

Hi I want to override the **set_value** function, but whatever I do nothing seems to work

here's what I've tried so far

```
POSScreen.OrderWidget.include({
        set_value: function(val) {
            this._super(val);
            var order = this.pos.get_order();
            if (order.get_selected_orderline()) {
                var mode = this.numpad_state.get('mode');
                if( mode === 'quantity'){
                    order.get_selected_orderline().set_quantity(val);
                }else if( mode === 'discount'){
                    console.log('sample output just to see changes');
                    order.get_selected_orderline().set_discount(val);
                }else if( mode === 'price'){
                    var selected_orderline = order.get_selected_orderline();
                    selected_orderline.price_manually_set = true;
                    selected_orderline.set_unit_price(val);
                }
            }
        },
```

I want to add my custom **mode** here but whatever I do even if I throw an error nothing happens my changes didn't apply

I've already modified some function in the screens and models this is the only function that I can't modify

Comment: did you included your jsscript to backend asset?

Comment: yes ```<template id="pos_inherit_assets_backend" name="whatever_name assets" inherit_id="point_of_sale.assets">
         <xpath expr="." position="inside">
             <script src="/tw_pos_inherit/static/src/js/model_inherit_pos.js" type="text/javascript"></script>```

Comment: is the template file in manifest? is the js function being called at all?